# Create a class in Javascript that can access local variables

Tags: javascript, scope, eval

I'm working on a debugger that injects code into already existing code. Which then use eval() to log and run it.

However eval() seems to work in only its existing scope. To overcome this I tried to add a class that i recreated in each local scope. But it doesnt work.

I've added code to ilustrate my problem. The first alert works as expected, I'm assuming that it is because MyClass is created in the same scope.

The second alert still display b as 10 even though I've set b in local scope to 20 inside the TestC function. And the last alert doesn't work at all eval() returns in console "Uncaught ReferenceError: c is not defined".

If I add the whole MyClass inside each function and the assign it, then it works, but that doesn't feel like an elegant solution. And can add 1000's of lines of code to a project.

http://jsfiddle.net/ekim/zryj3taq/2/

```
var MyClass = function()
{
    this.MyAlert = function(codex)
    {
        eval(codex);
    }
}

var b = 10;
var MyOne = new MyClass();
MyOne.MyAlert("alert(b);");

function TestC()
{
    var b = 20;
    var MyOne2 = new MyClass();
    MyOne2.MyAlert("alert(b);");

    var c = 20;
    var MyOne2 = new MyClass();
    MyOne2.MyAlert("alert(c);");
}


TestC();
```

Comment: Problem 1: You are using eval. eval runs in global scope...that is why the first one works because the variable b is in global scope.

Comment: What is the "real world" code, I am sure you are not using an alert. Why are you using a string?

Comment: I'm tracking Update,Binary,Logical and Assignment Expressions and IF blocks, loops, .. Blocks that contains function calls like "IF f(5)+5>10.." or a=f(5)+5; My helper function coverts this to helperF('Temp1+5',f(5),'f(5)'), the last 2 parameters can be 2,4,6,.. depending on multiple functions or nested functions. The reason is that I want to be able to log the output of the functions as well as the result. I can't pass the function outputs twice. If the function had some code global i++ etc. in it the inserted code would break the original algorithm.

Comment: sorry wrote wrong. if the code were var b=5; var a=f(b)+5+b; The helperF should be helperF('Temp1+5+b','f(b)'); The helper function evaluates and logs all the blocks after the first string parameter and then replaces Temp1,Temp2,... with the values that are returned and then evaluates (25+5+b) the string then return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`new Function(\[arg1\[, arg2\[, ...argN\]\],\] functionBody)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

```js
(function(){    
    var str = "return (A+B)*C";
    var myFunc = new Function("A","B","C", str);
    var result = myFunc(2,3,4);
    console.log(result);
}());



/* Example with function */
(function(){    
   
   var fncDouble = function (X) {
       return X*2;
   }

    var str = "return F(A)+B";
    var myFunc = new Function("F","A","B", str);
    var result = myFunc(fncDouble,3,1);
    console.log(result);
}());
```

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea you could run string code without using eval() at all.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no easy solution to this, as the `eval()` function just creates a new, separate compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `MyOne2.MyAlert.call(this, "alert(b)");`

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind this, unfortunately it doesnt change anything.